# Laradock - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` =

Tags: laravel, laradock

**When I try to migrate after set up laradock I get this error:**
I set up laradock following the main doc, everything works as it should but no when I create a new user from the browser.

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = cd_eloquent and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /Users/cristian/development/laravel/cd_eloquent/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known")
      /Users/cristian/development/laravel/cd_eloquent/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=mysql;port=3306;dbname=cd_eloquent", "cristian", "cristian", [])
      /Users/cristian/development/laravel/cd_eloquent/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

**.env**
Example .env following the main doc using **DB_HOST=mysql**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cd_eloquent
DB_USERNAME=cristian
DB_PASSWORD=cristian
```

**if I change my .env**
I change the **DB_HOST=127.0.0.1**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cd_eloquent
DB_USERNAME=cristian
DB_PASSWORD=cristian
```

**and then I get all the migrations**
Only works with 127.0.0.1 no with mysql

```
cd_eloquent git:(master) ✗ php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (0.04 seconds)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (0.05 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (0.08 seconds)
```

**When I try to signup, I get this error**

[image]

**if I change my .env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cd_eloquent
DB_USERNAME=cristian
DB_PASSWORD=cristian
```

**I get this error**

[image]

**What is wrong here?**

**laradock .env**

```
### MYSQL #################################################

MYSQL_VERSION=5.7
MYSQL_DATABASE=default
MYSQL_USER=default
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

**laradock sites**

[image]

**Example of site**

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # For https
    # listen 443 ssl;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    # ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt;
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default.key;

    server_name cd_eloquent.test;
    root /var/www/cd_eloquent/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel_access.log;
}
```

**Example phpmyadmin**

[image]

[image]

**Example of containers running**

[image]

**Docker-compose ps**

[image]

**Another example**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=laradock_mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cd_eloquent
DB_USERNAME=cristian
```

[image]

Comment: From inside your docker environment (i.e. .env) you have to reference database using the container name. See `docker-compose ps` for a list. Do not use localhost. Did you rename your containers? From your screenshot it looks like it is called `laradock_mysql` instead of `mysql`

Comment: I updated the post with the example I tried from you, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just retry `php artisan migrate:fresh` from your laradock workspace container it will work.
ex:
`docker-compose exec workspace bash`
`php artisan migrate:fresh`

Answer (score 0):

On laradock, if you're using mariadb instead of mysql use mariadb as the DB_HOST.

`DB_HOST=mariadb`

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you had to change the DB_HOST on `.env` In my case the IP was changed and the migrations run on my computer but not in the container which has another IP.

Answer (score -1):

On laradock each service has its own container thus localhost or 127.0.0.1 refers to the workspace container that doesn't have mysql in it, try:

```
DB_HOST=mysql
```

This would map the correct internal ip address using Docker's internal nameserver.